# 301 Redirect from web.config on IIS 6

Tags: asp.net, redirect, web-config, iis-6, http-status-code-301

I need to make an 301 Redirect from the web.config on a IIS 6 server (Windows 2003 Web Server). 
I'm a Apache-server guy, and do not have a clue about Windows Web Servers. I only have access to the server from FTP.

I have found the following in another question, but it does'nt seem to work:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to WWW" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url=".*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="^mydomain1.com$" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="http://www.mydomain2.com"
               redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

I need to redirect seperate pages from ***mydomain1.com*** to ***mydomain2.com***. 
Ex. ***mydomain1.com/somename*** should redirect to ***mydomain.com/someothername***

How can this be done?

**---- Edit ----**
After seeing another thread here on stackoverflow, my configuration now kind of looks like this:

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rule name="rule1">
            <match url="default.aspx"/>
            <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http://www.mydomain.com/somename/somename.aspx"/>
        </rule>
        <rule name="rule2">
            <match url="somename.aspx"/>
            <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Permanent" url="http://www.mydomain2.com/somename2/somename2.aspx"/>
        </rule>
    </rewrite>
</system.webserver><br>
```

**--- Edit 2 ----**
Code for redirecting the root:

Comment: You'd need http://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite installed to get that to work.  Is it?

Comment: I'll check up on that. I need to contact the hosting support. Their support could not help me with the answers to my questions either, so i hope they can answer this one.

Comment: Okay, the site is now moved to another server with IIS8 and url-rewrite installed. I have tried the above code again, but all i get is an error: 
"HTTP Error 500.19 - Internal Server Error
The requested page cannot be accessed because the related configuration data for the page is invalid."

Comment: Seen this error, you'll get that if URL Rewrite not installed.  To test, try removing the whole rewrite segment, should work fine, put it in, it'll fall over.

Comment: Thanks Daniel. I contacted the support again and explained the situation. They asked me to upload the web.config file again, so they could look at it. And suddently it works.

Comment: Now my biggest problem is to redirect the mydomain.com **mydomain.com/default.aspx** is redirecting, but not the root. How can i do that? I have tried with `<match url="/"/>` but doesn't work.

Comment: I figured it out - found this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018818/iis7-url-redirection-from-root-to-sub-directory)

Answer (score 0):

As far as I investigated, There is no way to redirect by web.config on IIS6.

[rewrite](https://www.iis.net/downloads/microsoft/url-rewrite) and [httpRedirect](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/iis/configuration/system.webserver/httpredirect/) directives can use only same or after IIS7.

But you can use [ISAP way with paid solution](http://www.isapirewrite.com/).

So, I think `Response.Redirect("direct to");`
is best way