# iis redirect subdomain to subfolder on same subdomain

Tags: asp.net, iis, redirect, web-config, url-rewriting

I have an IIS site and Im trying to use ReWrite 2.0 to redirect a particular subdomain to a sub folder. Within my IIS site I have it binded to two different domains:

- one.example.com
- two.example.com

When people visit one.example.com I want it to do nothing. When people visit http://two.example.com I want them to be redirected to http://two.example.com/subfolder.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3):

You need to add a match condition for the HTTP_HOST

```
<system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
        <rules>
            <rule name="two.example.com Redirect" stopProcessing="false">
                <match url="^\/?$" />
                <conditions>
                    <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern=".*two\.example\.com.*" />
                </conditions>
                <action type="Redirect" redirectType="Found" url="http://two.example.com/subfolder/{R:0}" />
            </rule>
       </rules>
    </rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Here's a decent overall reference for the module:
http://www.iis.net/learn/extensions/url-rewrite-module/url-rewrite-module-configuration-reference

A very late answer, but hopefully it helps someone.

Comment: This is causing an redirect loop for me. Do you know why?

Comment: @RobbieSmith Could you try making the match url="^\/?$" ? I feel like I must have had a working example back when I wrote this, but in looking at it now, I think that you should only match in this scenario to the root of the url, to ensure the rule isn't picked up after the redirect to the subdirectory. Let me know and I will edit the answer if that's correct. Thanks

Comment: I ended up doing a stupid human trick. in my root I created a default.aspx file with the contents `<% Response.Redirect("http://.../subfolder") %>`

Answer (score 0):

I presume you are using II7 or higher ?

IIS has a simple HTTP redirect function which is available per site listed in IIS.

Make sure you are in features view. Click on the site you want to redirect (In your case its http://two.example.com)

You should see this. Double click on HTTP Redirect[image: IIS View]

The you should see this. Enter your Redirect URL here (In your case its http://two.example.com/subfolder)

[image: HTTP Redirect View]

Comment: This will redirect all traffic to a destination. I want to redirect only for a certain domain & it redirects to a subfolder on the same domain.

Answer (score -1):

[This existing question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7031732/1453921) should solve your issue

```
<system.webServer>
<rewrite>
    <rules>
        <rule name="Root Hit Redirect" stopProcessing="true">
            <match url="^$" />
            <action type="Redirect" url="/menu_1/MainScreen.aspx" />
        </rule>
    </rules>
</rewrite>
</system.webServer>
```

Comment: Yes thanks I have tried this but this will do it for both domains. I only want to redirect two.example.com