# IIS Rewrite URL To Subfolder

Tags: iis-7, url-rewriting

Hi I am trying to match my Request URL and redirect to subfolder from Defauls Website.

My Default Website is **crm.domainname.com**. If someone try with this request ,it should redirect to **crm.domainname.com/subfolder**.

I tried this:

[image]

But it never redirect my request.

**UPDATE**

I make change and match with regular expression now.

[image]

It Works for 4-5 requests than again it stop redirecting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'Pattern' field is meant to filled with a regular expression. Check [this link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018818/iis7-url-redirection-from-root-to-sub-directory) for configuration options.

Comment: I tried with your suggetion, it works for 4-5 request and than again stop redirecting.