# Add a default sub directory to a site in web config?

Tags: asp.net, hyperlink, web-config

I have a website which is running fine locally, On the hosted domain it is placed in a sub folder.

```
Example:  

Localhost:1234/public/login.aspx

www.live.co.za/lsnew/public/login.aspx
```

The group hosting my site has put all my code in the file lsnew on the host domain. This has broken all my links.

I would like to add something in the web config i can turn on before hosting to add a sub directory to all my paths.

How do i add a default sub directory to follow the domain name?

I would like something similar to the web config defaultDocument, but instated of a page name i would like to have a default sub directory to follow my domain name.

Comment: It's a bit unclear what exactly you're asking, but I think you can use URL rewriting.

Comment: @CodeCaster Please see edit. I need help, even just so key words on what to look for.

Comment: So, have you researched URL rewriting?

Comment: @CodeCaster I'm looking through some links now, however i don't see anything looking like what i need.

Comment: Then edit your question to show and explain what your site does now and how that is wrong. What does _"add a sub directory to all my paths"_ mean **exactly**? Are the URLs in your HTML like `/public/login.aspx` (including leading slash) and you want them to become `/lsnew/public/login.aspx`?

Comment: @CodeCaster Yes i would like /lsnew added into my path's. I would also like it as a easy trigger to turn off and on.

Comment: Does a site already exist at `/`? Did you try [IIS7 URL Redirection from root to sub directory](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7018818/iis7-url-redirection-from-root-to-sub-directory)? Can't you rather ask for a new subdomain if all URLs are absolute to the root (`/`)?

Comment: A site already exists at the domain example www.livesite.com They have then added a folder and placed my site in that folder. www.livesite.com/lsnew I would just like something to defult the lsnew to my path's