# Redirect IIS's root to application root

Tags: iis, iis-8.5

I have several applications installed on IIS:

```
/abc
/bcd
```

Now I want to redirect users coming to `/` to the `/abc` website. Since the root is not part of any application, I cannot use IIS Rewrite Module which uses redirects defined in `web.config`.

So I installed `HTTP Redirection` in IIS and enabled the following:

[image]

This works, if the user enters exactly `http://example.com` or `http://example.com/`, the server redirects to `http://example.com/abc/`.

However, if the user enters `http://example.com/abc`, the server treats the request as *in the root directory*, so it applies a redirection too, leading to `http://example.com/abc/abc`.

I also tried checking the first checkbox (*Redirect all request to exact destination*), but this leads to a redirection loop from `http://example.com/abc` to `http://example.com/abc`.

**I want those users entering `example.com/abc` to stay there, and redirect users entering `example.com` to the `/abc` application. How can I do that?**

Answer (score 6):

To fix the redirect loop, you can add a trailing anchor link to the destination, for example: `/abc/#`. This prevents IIS from stripping the trailing slash and creating a redirect loop from `http://example.com/abc` to `http://example.com/abc`

[image: IIS HTTP Redirect Configuration]

### Example redirect

```
Request URL:https://example.com/abc
Request Method:GET
Status Code:302 Redirect

Response Headers
Location:https://example.com/abc/#
Server:Microsoft-IIS/8.0

Request URL:https://example.com/abc/
Request Method:GET
Status Code:200 OK
```

### URL rewrite module

Alternatively you can still use the URL rewrite module [as discussed here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7031732/2057785) even when it is for your root site and not an application. The `web.config` file should be present in your web root folder (typically `%SystemDrive%\inetpub\wwwroot`). You can also use the URL Rewrite UI in IIS Manager to add an inbound rule:
[image: IIS URL Rewrite Edit Inbound Rule]

This will redirect `http://example.com/` to `http://example.com/abc/`.

If the user enters `http://example.com/xyz` (and that file does not exist) they will not be redirected to `/abc` and will receive a `404`, unlike the HTTP redirect module above.

Comment: Why the pattern `^$`, could you please explain?